# GitHub like Horizon charts with Cubism.js

Tags: cubism.js

Is it possible to plot two values at the same time on the same axis with Cubism like GitHub does for their [code-frequency](https://github.com/openstack/swift/graphs/code-frequency) charts? I tried searching the web with no luck and it's not there in the documentation either. If it's not possible with Cubism, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think that it is possible as I myself had tried doing the same as what you had mention. But lucky there are other option which you may one to consider one of them like:

[Rickshaw.js](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/)